# Convert signed int number to unsigned whith shell script

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sh

I need to convert signed int32 number to unsigned using shell script

for example :

```
convert  Input : -256
Expected output: 4294967040
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I tried something like this for negative numbers:
SIGNED=-256
UNSIGNED=$((0x`printf '%x' $SIGNED | grep -Eo '.{8}$'`))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this can help you;

```
#!/bin/bash
input=$1
if [[ $input -lt "0" ]]; then
    output=$((4294967296+$input))
else
    output=$input
fi
echo $output


#signed int32;
#–2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647
#unsigned int32
#0 to 4,294,967,295
```

Answer (score 3):

Here goes, probably not the quickest, but seems to work

```
unsigned_to_signed()
{
    local hex=$(printf "0x%x" $(( $* )))
    local unsigned=$(printf "%u" $hex )
    echo $unsigned
}

unsigned_to_signed32()
{
    local hex=$(printf "0x%x" $(( $* & 0xFFFFFFFF )))
    local unsigned=$(printf "%u" $hex )
    echo $unsigned
}

unsigned_to_signed -256
18446744073709551360

unsigned_to_signed32 -256
4294967040
```